# ionic v2 image download and view is very slow

Tags: ionic2

I previously had a problem with loading images to my ionic app. Now, I am able to download an image into cache directory and then display it. However, an image now takes a longer time to load.

Here is a snippet of my typescript for the page relevant to image loading.

```
LoadImage(){

    const transfer = new Transfer();
    var url = someurl + this.hash + "/" + this.attachment;
    var uri = encodeURI(url);
    var filepath = cordova.file.cacheDirectory+ '/' + this.vacancy.attachment;//("/"+this.vacancy.attachment);
    transfer.download(uri,  filepath, true ).then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry );
        this.image = entry.toURL();
        console.log(this.image);

      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

      });
  }
```

Here is the relevant HTML part.

```
<img *ngIf="image" ng-cache [src]="image">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Ionic_Logo.svg/2000px-Ionic_Logo.svg.png">
```

I have also put the ionic logo for comparison.

Please explain how I can increase the speed of image loading.

Comment: are you loading multiple images in a page?

Comment: No, I am not, only one. However, I added the new image for comparison  to how it would appear

Comment: According to docs, ion-img is only meant to be used inside of virtual-scroll. Maybe try with that or just img tag

Comment: well, that is my mistake. I meant to put it with just the img tag

Comment: Did you find out anything in the end? Having the same issue...

Comment: Hi @Chris I solved this eventually by encoding the image in base64 format and then download it, since the transfer method is usually slow. It should work for you too